# Page viewer webpart, applying style sheets?

Tags: 2010, web-part

Can i apply css style sheet to a page viewer webpart ?

Comment: To the webpart itself or to the contained page?

Comment: i want to add in the contained page . I want to apply different styles to the content inside the page viewer wp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A page viewer web part is essentially a glorified iFrame, so you can do anything that you would normally be able to do with an iFrame (such as target specific elements of the web page within the iFrame with JavaScript). CSS styling of content within an iFrame is possible in some scenarios, but typically very unreliable across multiple browsers.

If we're talking SharePoint 2010 then (as a best practice) anything you deploy should be supported in IE, Firefox, Safari, and if you're Service Pack 1 or above, Chrome. Many targeted CSS solutions don't work reliably across all browsers. There's a [thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe) that discusses some of the options.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : Found a solution by doing programatically

Added a custom control to the page which will apply style sheet dynamically. 
So when i try to open the page the pageviewer runs the code and apply style sheet dynamically.
This is best and easiest of solution